# How to re-set custom HTTP Headers in BigQuery API calls

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to set a custom HTTP Auth Header in my HTTP Request to Big Query

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
    HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = httpRequest.getHeaders();
            httpHeaders.putAll(httpHeadersMap);
            httpRequest.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
        }
    };

    Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(httpRequestInitializer)
        .build();
```

The problem is that I need to refresh this Header every few hours.

So, how do I reset the header the NEXT time, because looks like the `setHttpRequestInitializer()` is baked into `Bigquery` object.

Comment: Can you give some background as to why you are trying to do this?

Comment: @GrahamPolley All our request in our company go through an HTTP Proxy server. And they have mandated to attach a -H "Proxy-Auth: blah" header onto the request for auth purposes.

Also, seems like every outgoing API request first goes through "accounts.google.com" and the header code that I have in the sample above is not adding it even to the very first request to "accounts.google.com"